# Bash Script skips dialog user input

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm currently writing a setup script to automatically install hadoop master and slaves. Since I sometimes need user input to configure IP addresses and so on I'm installing 'dialog' in my installation script. However, the script skips over the dialog and just continues. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(whoami) != "root" ];
then
    echo "Must be run as root."
    exit 1
fi

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade

sudo apt-get install -y dialog

choice=`dialog --clear --backtitle -"bla bla" --radiolist "Hadoop Install" 10 40 3 1 "Master" on "Slave" off 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`
dialog --clear
clear

TYPE="hadoopmaster"

case $choice in
    1)  echo "Master"
        TYPE="hadoopmaster";;
    2)  number=`dialog --clear --backtitle -"blaa" --  
        inputbox "Slave Number" 0 0 "" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`
        dialog --clear
        clear
        TYPE="hadoopslave"$number;;
esac

apt-get update
apt-get install -y curl
apt-get install -y git
```

Comment: What's going on with all the output redirection of the dialog? Isn't this overkill for what could be a simple `read -p "blah blah" choice` command?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: Opening a terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 and ./sudo myscript.sh. Hm does it only work if there is no X installed?

Comment: `set -vx` is your friend. Also using the `/full/path/to/dialog` might help. Good luck.

Comment: your first `dialog` command says: `Error: Expected 3 arguments, found only 2.`.  btw, it's recommended to add `set -e` for your script to exit on any  command fail. You might have just mist that error.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

```
choice=`dialog --clear --backtitle -"bla bla" --radiolist "Hadoop Install" 10 40 3 1 "Master" on 2 "Slave" off 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`
```

Thanks guys!